# What's differents between window and top javascript global variable?

Tags: javascript, window, global-variables, global

I discover on one external script, a new global var called `top`, but I don't see the difference with `window` variable ?!

external script exemple :

```
var doc  = top.document;
var re   = top.RegExp;
var nav  = top.navigator;
```

What's differents between window and top javascript global variable ?

Comment: Can you show us the code ?

Comment: @ANS I have edited

Comment: [site:stackoverflow.com javascript difference between window and top](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+difference+between+window+and+top)

Comment: [MDN `window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Window** represents current window context whereas **top** represents the context of topmost window.

If you are not using frames and everything in your page lies in single window then both are same.

But if you have **multiple frames** in page then **window** will represent the currently focused frame whereas **top** will represent the window which is holding all frames in your page.